# Error with DateTime mapping C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm working on a program that is pulling data from a SQLserver instance and manipulating it in a C# console application. I'm having trouble mapping dateTime value correcltly. I'm using Enterprise Library 5.
This is the error I get

> The Column DOB was not found on the IDataRecord being evaluated. This might indicate that the accessor was created with the wrong mappings

This is the param mapper interface

```
public class MyParameterMapper : IParameterMapper
{
    public void AssignParameters(DbCommand command, object[] parameterValues)
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@dateOfBirth";
        parameter.Value = parameterValues[0];
        parameter.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
}
```

In the class that is modeling the type of object which will have the mappings has this declaration `public DateTime? DateOfBirth {get; set;}`. The class in which I actually implement the interface has pases the DoB like this: `var matches = _objectAdapter.GetList(person.DateOfBirth.Value).ToList();`

The actual method that passes the query is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetList(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    const string sql = (@"SELECT FirstName, LastName
            FROM   Table
            WHERE  DOB = @dateOfBirth"); 
    var accessor = new SqlStringAccessor<Person>(_db, sql, new MyParameterMapper(),_myRowMapper);
    var people = accessor.Execute(dateOfBirth);
    return people;
}
```

The actual mapping is as follows:

```
private IRowMapper<Person> _myRowMapper = MapBuilder<Person>.MapAllProperties()
        .Map(x => x.FirstName).ToColumn("FirstName")
        .Map(x => x.LastName).ToColumn("LastName")
        .Map(x => x.DateOfBirth).ToColumn("DOB")
        .Build();
```

The column name is correct, so I'm not sure if this error has to do with interface or if there is some explicit casting I have to pass on DateOfBirth?

Answer (score 2):

Try add DOB to your select clause...

```
const string sql = (@"SELECT FirstName, LastName, DOB
                FROM   Table
                WHERE  DOB = @dateOfBirth");
```

Comment: Good catch @sparky , I was able to execute beyond that error, and through the debugger I was able to see that the column was mapped correctly, I have another error relating with the parameter but this time it has to do with a null value, I have to continue debugging to see what it could be. Can you explain why it worked when I added the DOB column to the select clause?

Comment: The Row Mapper code expected a column called DOB.   The SQL didn't bring this column back from the database (because the column actually isn't needed, but...)   However, the row Mapper doesn't know the column is not being used, so when it wasn't in the result set, it threw the error.